# Streamlit requirements.txt problem with pyodbc

Tags: python, github, web, streamlit, requirements.txt

I'm trying to deploy my streamlit app through the streamlit cloud and I'm able to run the app locally. As suggested on their website, I added a requirements.txt file to my github repo root. However, when I run the app, the following is what I get on the website:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs (if you're on Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower right of your app).
Traceback:
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/streamlit_news/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pyodbc
```

my requirements.txt looks like this:

```
pyodbc==4.0.39
```

The folder hierarchy looks like this in my github repo:

app_folder
`>secrets.toml`
`>.gitignore`
`>packages.txt`
`>requirements.txt`
`>app.py`

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much!

I was expecting it to get install the package using requirements.txt but I get an error in the import statement when I deploy the app to the web.

app.py

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import datetime
import pyodbc

#warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module="pandas.io.sql")
```

Comment: can you do a **pip list** and check whether the module is available? and im assuming that you ran pip -r requirements.txt?

Comment: @Kulasangar I haven't ran pip -r requirements.txt but my problem is that the web app isn't working. I built this repo from scratch and now it works on my local computer, but not on the web.

Comment: can you show us the app.py?